# Proper split of time series data where user behavior should be taken into consideration too

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, time-series

I have a dataset consisting of dated information about various user purchases.

| Time | user_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-15 | 1 | prod1 |
| 2023-08-15 | 1 | prod2 |
| 2023-08-15 | 2 | prod1 |
| 2023-08-16 | 1 | prod3 |
| 2023-08-16 | 2 | prod4 |
| 2023-08-16 | 3 | prod1 |
| 2023-08-16 | 3 | prod4 |

I want to split the data at 70:30 but it is important that there is no data leakage. The data is sorted and what I do want is to take into consideration for example that user_id = 1 has purchased 2 products on the 15th of August. If the 70:30 split means that the first purchase will stay in the training dataset and the second purchase will go in the test set, I believe this is in some way data leakage.

Of course, I may be wrong about my view on data leakage, but if I am not I would appreciate help in solving the issue so that my split takes into consideration the fact that a user's day purchases should not be split between the two datasets. The code below splits my data so that I don't have to worry about the issue I mentioned, but it cannot split it close to 70:30, it is closer to 60:40.

Also, the data cannot be shuffled because I will use it past behavior to predict future behavior.

```
def generate_mask(group):
    n_rows = len(group)
    train_size = int(n_rows * 0.7)
    return pd.Series([True] * train_size + [False] * (n_rows - train_size))

mask = user_prod_data.groupby(['user_id', 'time']).apply(generate_mask).reset_index(
    level=2, drop=True).sort_index().tolist()
```

Then the data is converted to tensorflow Dataset. Then the split happens here:

```
def splitting_data_tf(data_tf: tf.data.Dataset, use_time: bool, mask: list, random_seed: int = 18):
"""
Split TF data into train and tests
:param data_tf:
:param use_time:
:param mask:
:param random_seed:
:return:
"""
tf.random.set_seed(random_seed)

mask_tensor = tf.constant(mask, dtype=tf.bool)

train = data_tf.enumerate().filter(lambda idx, _: mask_tensor[idx])
test = data_tf.enumerate().filter(lambda idx, _: ~mask_tensor[idx])

# Remove enumeration indices
train = train.map(lambda idx, x: x)
test = test.map(lambda idx, x: x)

cached_train = train.apply(tf.data.experimental.dense_to_ragged_batch(batch_size=512)).cache()
cached_test = test.apply(tf.data.experimental.dense_to_ragged_batch(batch_size=512)).cache()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Use groupby 'Time' and track the cumulative percentage by date. Take the maximum date that is less than your train test split percentage.

**Steps**:

1. Keeping in line with previous responses, let's use the same sample dataset

```
data = {
    'Time': ['2023-08-15', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16'],
    'user_id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    'product': ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod1', 'prod3', 'prod4', 'prod1', 'prod4']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
total_rows = df.shape[0]

# Result:
#   Time        product
#   2023-08-15  3
#   2023-08-16  7
```

2. Get the cumulative count of items which are grouped by 'Time'.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Time')['product'].count().cumsum().reset_index()
df_grouped['percent'] = df_grouped['product'] / total_rows

# Result:
# Time          product percent
# 2023-08-15    3       0.428571
# 2023-08-16    7       1.000000
```

3. Filter the DataFrame and get the maximum date that falls in your train dataset

```
train_mask = (df_grouped['percent'] < .70)
test_mask = (df_grouped['percent'] >= .70)

max_train_date = df_grouped[train_mask]['Time'].max()

# Result:
# '2023-08-15'
```

4. Split your dataframe into train and test sets.

```
train_set_mask = (df['Time']<= max_train_date)
test_set_mask = (df['Time']> max_train_date)

df_train = df[train_set_mask].copy()
df_test = df[test_set_mask].copy()
```

**Complete Code**:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Time')['product'].count().cumsum().reset_index()
df_grouped['percent'] = df_grouped['product'] / total_rows

train_mask = (df_grouped['percent'] < .70)
test_mask = (df_grouped['percent'] >= .70)

max_train_date = df_grouped[train_mask]['Time'].max()

train_set_mask = (df['Time']<= max_train_date)
test_set_mask = (df['Time']> max_train_date)

df_train = df[train_set_mask].copy()
df_test = df[test_set_mask].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge you're facing is because you're ensuring each user's daily purchases are not split between the training and test datasets. Due to this, the split might not always be exactly 70:30.

However, if you still want to make it as close as possible to 70:30 while ensuring no split within user's daily purchases, you may need to consider shuffling the distinct combinations of `user_id` and `Time`. This will ensure at least the randomness in the dataset split.

Also instead of applying the mask directly on the grouped `user_id` and `Time`, I would go for iterating through the shuffled list and check the accumulated number of rows to decide whether it goes to train or test.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'Time': ['2023-08-15', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16'],
    'user_id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    'product': ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod1', 'prod3', 'prod4', 'prod1', 'prod4']
}

user_prod_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Here I calculated the number of rows that corresponds to 70% of the data
total_rows = len(user_prod_data)
train_rows_target = int(total_rows * 0.7)

# Here I shuffled the unique combinations of user_id and Time
unique_combinations = user_prod_data.groupby(['user_id', 'Time']).size().reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
shuffled_combinations = unique_combinations.sample(frac=1, random_state=18).to_dict('records')

mask = []
accumulated_train_rows = 0
for combination in shuffled_combinations:
    subset = user_prod_data[(user_prod_data['user_id'] == combination['user_id']) & (user_prod_data['Time'] == combination['Time'])]
    subset_size = len(subset)
    
    # If adding this group to the training data doesn't exceed the target, add it
    if accumulated_train_rows + subset_size <= train_rows_target:
        mask.extend([True] * subset_size)
        accumulated_train_rows += subset_size
    else:
        mask.extend([False] * subset_size)

print(mask)
```

### EDIT :

Since you mentioned the dataset is quite large, I thought about
accumulating the rows by iterating through the distinct combinations of `user_id` and `Time` in the sorted order.
For each unique combination, I checked if adding the entire group to the training data will surpass the 70% threshold.If not, I assign the group to the training set.
Once the threshold is surpassed, I assign the rest to the test set.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Time': ['2023-08-15', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-15', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16', '2023-08-16'],
    'user_id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    'product': ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod1', 'prod3', 'prod4', 'prod1', 'prod4']
}

user_prod_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate the number of rows that corresponds to 70% of the data
total_rows = len(user_prod_data)
train_rows_target = int(total_rows * 0.7)

mask = []
accumulated_train_rows = 0

grouped = user_prod_data.groupby(['user_id', 'Time'])

for _, group in grouped:
    subset_size = len(group)
    
    # If adding this group to the training data doesn't exceed the target, add it
    if accumulated_train_rows + subset_size <= train_rows_target:
        mask.extend([True] * subset_size)
        accumulated_train_rows += subset_size
    else:
        mask.extend([False] * subset_size)

print(mask)
```

Comment: but I am going to use data to make predictions for future purchases, I cannot afford to ruin the time part and shuffle it. I take into consideration the past behavior to predict the future one. This is why I do not shuffle.

Comment: Also, maybe I should mention that is it a quite big dataset. But I guess before time optimization I need to solve this issue.

Comment: You see, you didn't provide all the information so I assumed what I assumed

Comment: I added the comment in my question, I am sorry for the miss.